# появление элемента на сайте и отслеживание этого

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Имеется некая картинка которая появляется через некоторое время, с помощью этого скрипта я хотел отследить её появление

```
        while True:
            try:
                haz1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="blockverify"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/img')
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print('No element')
                time.sleep(10)
                continue
            print('Element')
            break
```

проблема в том что этот скрипт постоянно выдаёт

```
No element
No element
No element
No element
No element
No element
```

> даже после того момента когда картинка появилась на сайте

фрагмент кода (сайта) https://pastebin.com/nkCUPzVb

Comment: Без понимания, какие на сайте за HTML/CSS и возможно JS вряд ли удастся сказать, что не так в коде.

Comment: Единственное что могу скинуть это тег самой картинки

Comment: Смог я достать код https://pastebin.com/nkCUPzVb Сорри но второй код получился криво